Will the number of electron be conserved during Density functional theory self-consistent field calculation?
I am confused about the concept of charge neutrality in DFT calculations.
Let's say I have two silicon atoms in a primitive unit cell. Since the silicon has 14 protons and 14 electrons in a charge neutral state, I guess there must be 28 protons and 28 electrons in the primitive Si cell (let's avoid the periodic boundary condition for simplicity).
My specific questions are:

Electrons are treated as a wave function, so the number of electrons is treated as a density. Will I then get 28 if I integral the scf final electron density over the whole space?

Similar to the previous question, will I get the total number of electrons if I integral the all number of occupied states below Fermi-level(valence band in case of semi-conductor)?

During the SCF calculation, the electron density will change to match the wave function. Will the total number of electrons be conserved in the process, just varying spatially?


The reason I ask this question is that I saw a paper(Fig.8 in ref [1]) talking about DFT calculation of 'charge neutrality level (CNL)'. And it says that the CNL level is different from the Fermi level, but I don't understand how come it could be different.
[1]John Robertson, "Band offsets, Schottky barrier heights, and their effects on
electronic devices", J. Vac. Sci. Technol. A 31, 050821 (2013)

I put a disclaimer at the top of this answer: I only had a short peek at the paper you reference. Next, if you look at Wikipedia, the people there distinguish between the terms Fermi level and Fermi energy. I have not witnessed this discrimination in practice and thus for me the definition depends on the context. I am sure there will be numerous people who don't agree with this statement.
When you talk about this Fermi energy level two definitions are that it is the energy of the highest occupied state at a temperature of 0K or that it is at finite temperatures synonymous to the chemical potential as it appears in the Fermi-Dirac distribution.
All the definitions are based on the enforcement of charge neutrality, but there are differences in the electron state occupation function. The definition for 0K is simple: All states below are fully occupied, all states above are completely empty. Integrating all the states up to that level thus yields charge neutrality. If you employ the Fermi-Dirac distribution for the occupation of the states, states slightly above the hereby defined energy level are also partially occupied. For semiconductors with a large enough band gap and a small enough temperature, all the definitions yield numerically the same occupations and it is actually irrelevant where in the band gap you place the energy level discriminating between occupied and unoccupied states.
In general, depending on the occupation function and a possible band gap, there may be numerous - or even a range of - energy levels that yield charge neutrality.
In a strict sense, density functional theory is defined for a vanishing temperature. This is in agreement with the 0K definition of the Fermi energy level. In practice, however, it turns out that employing a smooth occupation function, e.g., the Fermi-Dirac distribution at a few hundred Kelvin, is very beneficial to the stability of such calculations. The temperature may then be reduced in a later step until the results don't change anymore. You may also use other occupation functions. One alternative may be the Methfessel-Paxton smearing, which is more mathematically and less physically motivated and defines another energy level fitting to the respective occupation function and conservation of charge neutrality.
Conservation of charge neutrality is essential for density functional theory calculations on periodic systems. The most basic quantity that can be obtained for such calculations is the total energy per unit cell. However, there are several energy contributions that are related to the charge density in the unit cell interacting with a potential originating from all charges in the complete space, e.g., the Hartree energy or the interaction between the electron charge density and the nuclear charges. If you wouldn't have charge neutrality, the sum of these energy contributions would diverge, because of the long range of the Coulomb interaction. Conservation of charge neutrality is thus a condition that is enforced by density functional theory codes for periodic systems. It is used to calculate a "Fermi energy level" or a similar energy that is specified by the respective occupation function.
The question whether you obtain 28 electrons if you integrate the electron charge density over the unit cell also depends on whether your DFT calculation employs the pseudopotential approximation to abstract from core electrons or it treats all electrons within the framework of DFT. In the latter case you obtain 28 electrons, in the pseudopotential case you obtain the number of electrons that you treat as valence electrons, though this number will also be conserved.
